# Cannot get objectId even inside saveInBackground()?

Tags: android, parse-platform, objectid

I cannot retrieve a created object's objectId, even inside the `public void done`.

```
occasion.saveInBackground(new SaveCallBack(){
    @Override
    String string = occasion.getObjectId();
})
```

And it just returns `null`and crashes the app with a NullPointerException. Why is it null? It saved it successfully. No object id, why? :(

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
 occassion.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {                
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(e==null){
                    String string = occasion.getObjectId();
                }
            }
  });
```

Comment: You're kidding right? This is exactly the same of what I posted in the question, except without a callback. Pretty much EXACTLY the same thing. -,-

Comment: Have you checked your object saved in parse table or not. May be your object is not saved in parse and it gives exception you should check exception before accessing object  details.

Comment: I didnt mention the exception to save typing time. I DO have an if else statement checking for an exception, next time I upload I'll put my age, because you know, questions' answers depend on brain level -.-